# University Dissertation

Tags: sound-design, research, dissertation

Hi everyone,

Im starting to do research for my dissertation and I really want to do it on an area of Sound Design. Im still pretty unsure on what exactly it is I am going to write about so I was wondering if anyone on here could give me some ideas? Ideally it has to be something that hasn't had a lot research already documented about and that I can define key questions to research and conclude my findings.

If anyone has any ideas or leads that would be a great help!
Sam